# How to deploy aspdotnetstorefront source code changes?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, deployment, aspdotnetstorefront

I'm implementing an AspDotNetStorefront (ASPDNSF) site for a client, they've purchased the source code and I'm just trying to do something simple like add an ID for CSS styling to the product images.

I've gone into the source and made the AspDotNetStorefrontCore.XSLTExtensionBase.LookupProductImage() method just return the string "TEST" expecting any product image to be replaced with "TEST", compiled the solution using Visual Studio's build. It builds successfully and the DLLs in the /web/bin directory now reflect modified dates the same as my build time, but the rendered page does not reflect my changes. I've reset the cache through the ASPDNSF admin page, but still no change.

Any idea what step I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be me being an idiot. Many of the methods in XSLTExtensionBase have several overloads, I was just making the change in the wrong overload. Simply compiling the project is all you need to do to deploy, but you have to change the right code for it to render what you want!